# Move emails to specific folder by email domain

Tags: vba, outlook

After googling a lot I found the below piece of code to move emails to a specific folder. But this code is moving emails only when entire email address matches with the hardcoded email address in the code. Is ther any way to move all emails from a specific domain like '@gmail.com' or '@msn.com'?

```
    Option Explicit
Public Sub Filter_Move_Emails()
'   // Declare your Variables
    Dim Inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim SubFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim Items As Outlook.Items
    Dim lngCount As Long
    Dim AddressPart() As String

'    Set Inbox Reference
    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set Items = Inbox.Items

'   // Loop through the Items in the folder backwards
    For lngCount = Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set Item = Items(lngCount)

        If Item.Class = olMail Then
            AddressPart = Split(Item.SenderEmailAddress, "@")
            Select Case LCase(AddressPart(UBound(AddressPart)))

'               // Email_One
                Case "gmail.com"

'                   // Set SubFolder of Inbox
                    Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders("Filtered")
                    Set Item = Items.Find("[SenderEmailAddress] = 'ABC@gmail.com'")
                    If TypeName(Item) <> "Nothing" Then
'                       // Mark As Read
                        Item.UnRead = False
'                       // Move Mail Item to sub Folder
                        Item.Move SubFolder
                    End If

            End Select
        End If
    Next lngCount

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You are checking the entire `SenderEmailAddress` and not just the domain part.

Perhaps the easiest approach is to use Split on "@" and then test the second part:

```
Dim AddressPart() As String

:  :  :

AddressPart = Split(Item.SenderEmailAddress,"@")
Select Case LCase(AddressPart(UBound(AddressPart)))
  Case "gmail.com"

  :  :  :

  Case "google.com"

  :  :  :

  Case Else

  :  :  :

End Select
```

`Case Else` is optional.  You could use to handle all other domains if necessary.

**Other Issues**

I have never found a use for `On Error GoTo Label` and do not understand why so many "experts" include it in their code. *(If anyone knows a use please add a comment describing that use.)* I suggest you delete all this error code.  Without this code, any error will cause the code to stop on the statement causing the error.  Some errors are transient and simply restarting the code clears the error.  If the error is not transient, you need to identify why that statement is giving an error and how to avoid it.  Often you can add tests for potential error conditions. Perhaps the item is not a MailItem and does not have property `SenderEmailAddress`.  If the error cannot be avoided, try something like:

```
Dim ErrNum As Long

  :  :  :

ErrNum = 0
On Error Resume Next
' Statement that gives error
ErrNum = Err.Number
On Error Goto 0
If ErrNum <> 0 Then
  ' Code to handle error 
Endif
```

I remember when a standard installation had a single Inbox and `olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)` returned a reference to that Inbox. The standard now seems to be one Inbox per email account plus one in "Outlook data file" with the unused Inbox in "Outlook data file" being the default. If your code does not find any emails, come back and I will tell you how to reference the correct Inbox.

Comment: This type of error handling is for non-programmers to report to you what they saw so you could fix the error. It is useful in VBA as you would have put the code in while the Office user went for coffee. That user would be unpleasantly surprised when the VB editor appeared without this error handling.

Comment: You are correct Tony. The Error handler is none of the use for me either. I have removed those from the original code. I have updated the script with your Split code however, It seems I have not done it correctly! Can you please let me know where to update and what to do with ``Set Item = Items.Find("[SenderEmailAddress] = 'ABC@gmail.com'")``?

Comment: I would delete `Set Item = Items.Find("[SenderEmailAddress] = 'ABC@gmail.com'")`.  You have already found that `Item` is an email you wish to move to SubFolder.  This attempts to find a different email.

Comment: I would also delete `If TypeName(Item) <> "Nothing" Then` and the matching `End If`.  You have already checked `Item.Class = olMail` so `TypeName(Item) <> "Nothing` must be False..

Comment: Lastly, I would take `Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders("Filtered")` outside the For loop.  You only need to set `SubFolder` once.